# Good summary of highschool to university chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

DISCLAIMER: I've browsed similar questions, but sadly they refer to books that're either too basic or too specialized.

Hello. I'm studying mechanical engineering (1st year), and we have to do a module in chemistry. It's mostly highschool chemistry (equilibrium, redox reactions, acids and bases, ...) with small snippets from unknown topics, such as thermodynamics and crystal structures. We are now beginning with "the chemistry of non-metals", and will eventually cover "the basics of organic chemistry" and "the chemistry of metals and solids". The problem is, we've gotten a new professor who's awful as an educator: he barely speeks the language, and never prepares the lessons. Instead, he just clicks through powerpoint presentations, slowly reading them out, while facing the screen.

I've found that - although more productive than his "lessons" - just reading the presentations is not enough. I recognize what I already know, but require an unreasonable ammount of time to understand the rest, which usually involves browsing wikipedia.

That's why I'd like to ask if anyone could suggest a book that summerizes highschool chemistry, and ventures into topics above highschool level in a way someone with a highschool education would understand. Obviously, alternative mediums such as videos are also fine. I just want something that more or less complements the lectures, and can always just google whatever details are not covered.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think Khan Academy is pretty good for chemistry. I am a second year chemical engineering student and I find that the videos are still helpful as a quick refresher for topics I've gotten a little rusty in.

Comment: The good news is that I'm writing this text book. The bad news is that it's not going to be ready any time soon... :(